# TextView Getting the Ellipsized Text Value

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

How can I get the ellipsized text value which is shown on the screen? For example; I try to write "sadasdasdasdadaadasasad" on a textview and this text is long for the textview and it is shown as "sadasdas..." What I want here is to get that ellipsized text value in code. How can I get it?

Comment: If I want to use substring method, I have to know the index that the ellipsis starts...

Comment: Use `.lastIndexOf("...")` for that.